# Adjunction between FinCat and Set that generates a Bimonad on Set

Tags: category-theory

I am interested to know if there are any adjunctions between FinCat (the cat of finite categories and functors) and (Fin)Set, which generate a bimonad on (Fin)Set.  You can find the definition of bimonad [given here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1163).

Comment: Have you realized that the exactness properties of adjoints are extremely severe? E.g. of $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{FinCat}$ were the left adjoint, then it would preserve colimits, and thus $L(X)$ is the $|X|$-fold coproduct of $L(1)$ with itself. By plugging in any infinite set $X$, the finiteness restriction implies $L(1) = \varnothing$, and thus $L(X) = \varnothing$ for every set $X$.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I guess my next move is to consider Bimonads on Finset generated by adjunctions to FinCat.  If you think that's possible, I will update my question.